# Blender shut down while exporting psk/psa file

Tags: animation, export

I'm a Blender newbie and all I know about it is what you can find in YouTube-Tutorials. Now I have the problem, that I have to export a .psk/psa file from Blender (2.75a) and every time I try it, Blender stops answering and crashes.

It is a makeHuman file imported in Blender, that I animated with the Dope sheet and the NLA Editor. In the tutorials, they say, that I have to set the cursor into the center (0/0/0) and the scale to (1/1/1) and so I did. I also joined the seperate Meshes of the body, hair and cloths, to have only one mesh parented.

Can anybody help me to create a .psk/psa NPC without crashing Blender?

Thank you very much.